# Changing references to Objects java

Tags: java

Code from CCI book:

```
public class ListNode {

  int val;
  ListNode next = null;

  ListNode(int x) {
    this.val = x;
  }
```

And this:

```
  public void appendToTail(int d) {
    ListNode end = new ListNode(d);
    ListNode n = this;
    while (n.next != null) {
      n = n.next;
    }
    n.next = end;
  }
```

Original: 5 -> 10 -> 15

As I understand, in this case "n" and "this" refer to same object yet, after debugging and stepping through:

"n" becomes 15 -> 20

**"this" becomes 5 -> 10 -> 15 -> 20**

How can this be? When I change "n", "this" should change as well?

So everything I did on "n" ,BESIDES appending 20, did not reflect on "this".

UPDATE:

Anyone who has same question should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73021/6817610).

Comment: Can you please post your entire code block? The behavior depends on where the `appendToTail` method lives.

Comment: @Barett it lives in  ListNode class. Above is the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your while loop you say:

```
n = n.next
```

When that line of code executes you change the value of n from "this" to n.next. This points to the current link object in the list and next points to a completely different object. As you walk your way through the linked list the value of n keeps updating as you pass through each link in the linked list.

When you get to the end of the linked list there is no next, i.e. value of n is null. So you exit the while loop and add a new link to the end of the linked list.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3):

> […] the keyword `this` denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method or default method was invoked […]

You only invoke `appendToTail(int)` on one particular node of your list, so `this` always refers to the same object. If you want to "step into" each node during debugging, you could change the implementation as follows:

```
public void appendToTail(int d) {
    if (next != null) {
        next.appendToTail(d);
    } else {
        next = new ListNode(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.